# MySQL: CASE statement in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, case

I was wondering if this is possible to put a CASE statement in the FROM clause... in MySQL?
something like:

```
SELECT id1 FROM ref_table AS rt WHERE
EXISTS 
   (SELECT rt.id FROM 
      (CASE rt.table
         WHEN 'tbl1' THEN tbl_1
         WHEN 'tbl2' THEN tbl_2
         WHEN 'tbl3' THEN tbl_3
      END) AS tbl
   WHERE tbl.id2 = rt.id_table)
```

Comment: There's no way with anything similar to this syntax, but if you could describe what your "end goal" with the query is, there may be an alternate solution.

Comment: actually, that's not a real need, i was just wondering if something like that is possible or not... as i know about case statement in the where but never seen any of this in from clause and thus my question... :)

Comment: The result of a `CASE` expression cannot be a table. So no. You can rewrite the query with `OR` and 3 EXISTS subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a `CASE` expression cannot be a table, so no, you can't use this syntax. You can rewrite the query with `OR` (or `CASE`) and 3 `EXISTS` subqueries:

```
SELECT id1 FROM ref_table AS rt WHERE
CASE rt.table
    WHEN 'tbl1' THEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_1 t WHERE t.id2 = rt.id_table)
    WHEN 'tbl2' THEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_2 t WHERE t.id2 = rt.id_table)
    WHEN 'tbl3' THEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_3 t WHERE t.id2 = rt.id_table)
END ;
```

More readable, with `OR`:

```
SELECT id1 FROM ref_table AS rt WHERE
   rt.table = 'tbl1' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_1 t WHERE t.id2 = rt.id_table)
OR rt.table = 'tbl2' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_2 t WHERE t.id2 = rt.id_table)
OR rt.table = 'tbl3' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_3 t WHERE t.id2 = rt.id_table)
;
```